# Excel Macro to search certain texts in row 1 from one sheet, copy the column under the text, and paste to a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am quite new to Excel Macro and need some help to achieve the following task.

I have two sheets in the same workbook; one is the main sheet that can be edited, and the other one is to extract certain columns from the main sheet. Since the main sheet may have columns inserted or deleted, my approach is to input specific titles that I would extract to sheet 2 (blank sheet initially), look up/match these texts/column titles in sheet 1 (main sheet); then, copy the entire column under that match column title and paste it to sheet 2.

I have the following code, but errors still pop up. Since I am not quite familiar with Macro syntax, I am not so sure if this approach is applicable. I do appreciate any help, comment, or suggestion. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim r As Long

For i = 1 To 30
    For j = 1 to 30
        If Sheets(2).Cells(1, j).Value = Sheets(7).Cells(1, i).Value Then
           For r = 2 To 1000
               Sheets(2).Cells(r, j).Copy
               Sheets(7).Cells(r, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
               Sheets(7).Cells(r, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue
           Next r
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What error and on which line?

Comment: As a start, instead of looping with `r` through all the rows to copy/paste the entire column you can do: `Sheets(2).Cells(1, j).entirecolumn.Copy` and it will capture the whole column. You'll get rid of one nested loop.

Comment: My error is in the line: Sheets(7).Cells(r, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue.  I also tried the method Rémi suggested. I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd better use `Find()` method of `Range` object to find values in a range

so you may want to use this code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim f As Range, mainShtHeaderRng As Range, blankShtHeaderRng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim mainSht As Worksheet, blankSht As Worksheet

    Set mainSht = Worksheets("mainSht") '<--| set your "main" sheet
    Set blankSht = Worksheets("blankSht") '<--| set your "blank" sheet

    Set mainShtHeaderRng = mainSht.Rows(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| set your header range in the "main" sheet
    Set blankShtHeaderRng = blankSht.Rows(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| set your header range in the "blank" sheet
    For Each cell In blankShtHeaderRng '<--| loop through "blank" sheet headers...
        Set f = mainShtHeaderRng.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--|... and search them between the "main" sheet headers
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if found...
            Range(f, mainSht.Cells(mainSht.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy '<--| copy "main" sheet corresponding column doqwn to its last non empty cell...
            cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats '<--| ... and paste formats...
            cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues '<--| ... and values to "blank" sheet current header column
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the code. I still have Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' or object '_Worksheet' failed for the line with Range(f,  ...)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in that line and when the code hits that line query all relevant variables in the Immediate Window

Comment: You could for instance type "?f.Address" (without quotation marks) and press Return to see what's the address of "main" sheet cell where it found "cell.Value". You could also type "?cell.Value" and press Return and "?mainSht.Cells(mainSht.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)" and press Return.

Comment: Did you change "mainSht" literal in "Worksheets("mainSht")" with the actual name of your "main" sheet? And the same for "Worksheets("blankSht")"?

Comment: It looks like "mainSht.Cells(mainSht.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)" is taking the correct value (it is the value in the last row of the first column that matches), but the value is not displaying in the blank sheet. Thanks. I am learning a lot.

Comment: If "Range(f, mainSht.Cells(mainSht.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp))" doesn't throw any error and since "f" is already ok (we're there after the positive result of "If Not f Is Nothing Then" check) then I could think of two possibilities: 1) we must add "mainSht." before "Range" 2) there could be merge cells in row 1 of "mainSht. Both are "blind" shots since I'm not by my PC to check them.

Comment: It looks like the problem is solved! As you suggested, I added "mainSht." before "Range(f,". Also, I remember that the first column of the main sheet has a couple of merged cells. I do not have the workbook with me but made up a similar one to test. I will test on the actual workbook when I get to work on Tuesday. Anyways, it works on the test sheet. Thank you very much for your help!  :)